# How can I configure these docker containers using a docker-compose.yml instead of a run command?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have 2 standalone containers that I have been building and running all at once with the following run commands:

Redis container:

```
docker run -v C:\Users\me\some_directory\redis.windows.conf:/redis- 
settings/redis.conf --name my_local_redis -p 6379:6379 redis gosu redis:redis 
redis-server /redis-settings/redis.conf
```

rabbitmq container:

```
docker run -d --hostname devlab --name rabbitmq-server -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

I've looked at the docker-compose documentation and I can see how to bind mount (-v in the run command) the relevant directory in the first run command, but how can I pull an existing image from docker hub and execute the gosu command via a docker-compose yml?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull an image from the docker hub, you only have to specify the image name in your compose file with the `image` directive. To run a specific command, you use `command`.

Be careful though, `command` will override your `CMD`, meaning it will change which process is launched by your container. In the case of redis, the `CMD` is `redis-server`. You could use `command: gosu redis:redis redis-server ...`

So it would be something like :

```
services: 
  my_local_redis:
    image: redis
    [...]
    ports: 
      - 6379:6379
    command: gosu redis:redis redis-server /redis-settings/redis.conf
```

I will let you figure out the rest !

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but I got the following error after running the command with gosu: error: exec: "&&": executable file not found in $PATH. Any idea why this works with run but not in the docker-compose yml?

Comment: Can you try without "&&" ?

Comment: You should definitely do it without "&&", I changed my answer. I was wrong about how gosu worked.

Comment: `command:` specifically overrides Dockerfile `CMD` and it is identical to passing a command after the `docker run image-name`.

Comment: That is correct, I've written to quickly. I corrected the answer.